# Inverse recursively tree menu on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, tree

I have a very simple recursive category tree table in my website

```
id
name
parent_id
```

Normally people wants to show the whole tree from the parents to their children

In my case I have the children ids and I need to do the inverse, create the tree from the children to their parents

Let's suppose that I have the following tree:

```
1 - Computer
 2 - Storage
  5 - HDD
  6 - SSD
 3 - Motherboard
  7 - AMD
  8 - Intel
 4 - Graphics Card  
  9 - Nvidia
  10 - AMD
```

and I have the ID of the children categories 6 and 10

```
6 - SSD
10 - AMD
```

in one select I need to retrieve all the parents of these categories 6 and 10 to create a tree like this:

```
1 - Computer
 2 - Storage
  6 - SSD
 4 - Graphics Card  
  10 - AMD
```

So, how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

If you know the maximum number of sub-levels, for example 3, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.id, t2.name, t3.id, t3.name
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2
    ON t1.parent_id = t2.id
INNER JOIN table t3
    ON t2.parent_id = t3.id
WHERE t1.id IN (6, 10)
```